# Subscription to ActivatedRoute.params isnt triggered

Tags: angular, routes, rxjs, angular-router

The problem is that my component is not redrawn when I navigate between two similar URLs.  For example, when the user is look at `http://localhost:8088/#/app/route/study/6/detail` and then navigates to `http://localhost:8088/#/app/route/study/7/detail`, the `StudyComponent` is correctly reloaded.  However, the `DetailComponent` is **not reloaded**.  I think the reason is that the `params` of the detail did not change, so Angular thinks it is ok to not reload.  But in my case the details *depend on the parent params*.

How can I fix this?

My routes:

```
const studyRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: RouteComponent,
        children:  [
            {path: 'study/:id', component: StudyComponent,
            children: [
                {path: 'detail', component: DetailComponent },
                {path: 'parts', component: PartsComponent }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
];
```

All my components are initialized like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loader = this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.onLoad());
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.loader.unsubscribe();
}
```

When I navigate between the details *of different studies* the `onLoad` is never called in the `DetailComponent`.

Comment: what is this,loader?

Comment: angular will not re instantiate the `DetailComponent` in your example, thats the default reuse strategy of the router. See https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5

Comment: @Sajeetharan I think is pretty obvious what this.loader is lol

Comment: What are you using for this.route? It should be ActivatedRoute, which should work for you. However keep in mind ngOninit is not necessarily going to be called every time you go to a new component so you should not rely on that method if your intention is to called this.onLoad on route change.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo i guess its loader :P.  may be i am not an expert as you :)

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta, yes `this.route` is the injected `ActivatedRoute`.  I am not relying on the `ngOnInit` being called.  However, I expect the `this.onLoad` to be called, which it is not.

Comment: @Sajeetharan guess you are right ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To react on changes to the `:id` parameter at the `DetailComponent` level, youll need to do the following changes:

```
// detail.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.loader = this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => this.onLoad());
}
```

This is because the path `detail` in your routes **does not** define the `:id` parameter, the parent of it does. So the changes are reflected at that level in the router state tree.

Comment: @JotaToledo, man you are awesome! this works perfectly!  For others novices like me, this is a useful tutorial  https://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/

Comment: Thanks. I had the same issue as well.